# Visual Studio 2012, Publish (Web Deploy) - Code First Migrations not changing web.config

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, webdeploy

I am using the publish tool from Visual Studio 2012 for the first time - locally as a test.

I have followed this tutorial:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-production

I can publish the site files fine, they work. But the code first migrations do not seem to work & no database is created. Even if I create the database manually, it doesn't change (for this test it is the same SQL Server instance that the main site is on - just with 'stage' added to the end of the name).

I also see no apparent attempt to perform any migrations in the output window of VS - just file & folder creation.

Am I missing something?

[image]

[image: Publish wizard settings]

**Update**

According to this article some references should be added to the web config to enable code first migrations on the target server. They aren't being added to the local config - and the web.config on the target server isn't there (I think it's compiled for deployment so I can't see it?).

Should it be adding this to the local web.config first? Is this the problem? If so why isn't the publish wizard creating it and exactly what would I need to enter?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28WebApplicationProjects.PackagePublishOverview%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework

[image]

Comment: If you create your DB manually, do you later have access to it from the application? In other words, is your connection string valid?

Comment: checking 'enable code first migrations' is not adding anything to the web.config - shouldn't it be?

As the database is not being created (no tables etc) - it's hard to tell, but the connection string does work (it's all local for testing)

Comment: The connection string works for the deployed database from my app if I update the connection string as a test.

Perhaps it is a permissions issue - though not really sure how to test or fix that?!

Comment: I have tried putting this in the Layout.cshtml:          @System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyAppEntities"]. In the source app, it outputs the connection string on the page - when deployed the front page displays fine (no data connection required) - but it doesn't output that string, and no pages requiring data connection work.

Comment: There is also no 'web.config' file in the root of the deployed app (maybe because it's compiled somewhere?) - looks like it can't find the connection string for some reason.

Comment: I had a similar problem when deploying to Azure for the first time.  The solution was to add
            var context = new EFDbContext();
            context.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
to the Application_Start() method in Global.asax. ymmv.

Comment: Thanks - I've done it, now the error that only happened when I hit a database connected page - now happens on the front page (on the 'createifnotexist' line.

I think this is a permissions issue - it can't find the database - any ideas? This is the error: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: I've done it = added your code. I have not fixed the problem (FYI)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem went away when I deployed to a Windows Server 2008 server - rather than a local test site.

I did have to create the database and give permission to the appropriate IIS user - but after that it worked fine.