# ASP-MVC Code-first migrations checkbox not active

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, webdeploy

I'm using VS Community 2013. I'm trying to web deploy an ASP-MVC app. I can deploy the app, but it can't create the database. When I set up the web deploy, the box for "Execute code first migrations (runs at application start)" checkbox is grey under my context. It is active for the "ApplicationDbContext (DefaultConnection).

I tried `enable-migrations` in the package manager console. I got some informative messages that helped me with the correct switches. My command was

```
Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName Gators3.Models.ApplicationDbContext -enableautomaticmigrations
```

I also noticed that the changes to my Web.config talked about [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28WebApplicationProjects.PackagePublishOverview%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework) are not being made. In fact, I don't even have a `<contexts>` section.

I've tried some of the tricks in other SO threads such as

["Execute Code First Migrations" checkbox disappeared from my publish profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664459/execute-code-first-migrations-checkbox-disappeared-from-my-publish-profile)

[Execute Code first Migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30392140/execute-code-first-migration)

[Visual Studio 2012, Publish (Web Deploy) - Code First Migrations not changing web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758894/visual-studio-2012-publish-web-deploy-code-first-migrations-not-changing-we)

But nothing has helped.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me to. I tried deleting things, and re-enabling migrations, and rebooting, and restarting Visual Studio and ...

I gave up. I now have the following in my Web.Dev.config (for deploying to my dev server):

```
 <entityFramework>
    <contexts xdt:Transform="Insert">
        <context type="LDS.Models.ApplicationDbContext, LDSAssembly">
            <databaseInitializer type="System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2[ 
 [LDS.Models.ApplicationDbContext, LDSAssembly], 
 [LDS.Migrations.MigrationConfiguration, LDSAssembly]
], EntityFramework" />
        </context>
    </contexts>
</entityFramework>
```

I can't tell the different in terms of behavior. I deploy new code with new migrations and the schema is up-to-date when my code executes. I probably pay a performance penalty to ensure the db is at the right version, but I'm too far in bed with Entity to change for this project.